# How to show that $Y^2 \ge [E(Y|Z)]^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let Y and Z be two random variables, how to show that $$ Y^2 \ge [E(Y|Z)]^2$$

Can anyone give me any hint or idea of how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming $Y\ge0$, this is equivalent to $Y\ge E(Y|Z)$, which is certainly not true. For example, if $Z$ is discrete, then $E(Y|Z)$ is the average value of $Y$ over the set $Z=z$, so the true value of $Y$ will be sometimes greater and sometimes less than $E(Y|Z)$.

Comment: This relation holds only in expected-value terms, i.e. $E[Y^2] \ge E([E(Y|Z)]^2)$

Answer (score 2):

This result is false. Consider the case when $Y$ and $Z$ are independent; then $\mathbb E[Y \mid Z] = \mathbb E[Y]$.